# How can I make Azure functions work with an existing Service Bus Topic trigger?

Tags: azure-functions

Been through the documentation and still not clear how this works. I have the following function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "name": "message",
      "direction": "in",
      "subscriptionName": "notifications",
      "topicName": "order-placed",
      "connection": "orders",
      "accessRights": "Manage"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

The connection string above is correct as per the doc. The subscription "notifications" does not exist - is this created by Azure functions or do I have to create a subscription for the topic using another mechanism? My function does not get called when I send a message to the bus targetting that topic. No subscription, no errors and no logs. I tried creating the subscription manually and that did not work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [sample ServiceBusTopicTrigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/tree/dev/sample/ServiceBusTopicTrigger) on github, and here is the documentation for the [ServiceBusTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus).

Make sure that `orders` is an app setting for your app with a valid manage connection string.

If your function app has more than one service bus connection, check to make sure that you're using the correct one in the portal.

If you provide a connection string with manage rights (in the portal you should see manage,send,listen) we will [automatically create the topic and subscription for you](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/Listeners/ServiceBusSubscriptionListenerFactory.cs#L36).

Also, check the host logs for your app, in your storage account or the kudu scm site `<yourapp>.scm.azurewebsites.net/debugconsole` -> LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host

Comment: Looking through the host log really helped - I was missing the entry from the host.json - it was as simple as that. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Links now appear to be broken.

Comment: links are broken and I could not reproduce the "automatically create the topic and subscription for you" behavior. @matt-mason could you please refresh this?